# WPF alternative to a sequence of DataTriggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, datatrigger

Currently I add a specific icon for each parent label of a tree. I evaluate the same value of the parent node multiple times. This is time consuming. Is there a simplified way that I can implement in XAML? Probably an enumeration declared as window resource?

```
    <!-- custom icons for the root nodes -->
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Header.NodeTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem, AncestorLevel=2}}"
           Value="Sequences">
        <Setter Property="Source"
        TargetName="Folder"
        Value="/Images/sequence.png" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Header.NodeTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem, AncestorLevel=2}}"
           Value="Triggers">
        <Setter Property="Source"
        TargetName="Folder"
        Value="/Images/trigger.png" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Header.NodeTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem, AncestorLevel=2}}"
           Value="Views">
        <Setter Property="Source"
        TargetName="Folder"
        Value="/Images/view.png" />
    </DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Binding Converter like this:

```
public class NodeTitleToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> uris = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "Sequences", "pack://application:,,,/Images/sequence.png" },
        { "Triggers", "pack://application:,,,/Images/trigger.png" },
        { "Views", "pack://application:,,,/Images/view.png" },
    };

    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string uri;
        return uris.TryGetValue(value as string, out uri)
            ? new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri))
            : null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Instead of multiple DataTriggers, you can now write a single Binding like this:

```
Source="{Binding Header.NodeTitle,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem, AncestorLevel=2}
    Converter={StaticResource NodeTitleToImageConverter}}"
```

or in a Style Setter:

```
<Setter Property="Source" TargetName="Folder"
    Value="{Binding Header.NodeTitle,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem, AncestorLevel=2}
        Converter={StaticResource NodeTitleToImageConverter}}" />
```